Spring boot set application property from a library in application properties
I am looking for a way to set some application properties via a custom library, that I am looking to create, directly in the .props/.yml file as opposed to creating the configs programmatically
e.g.
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    username: "${MyCustomSecretsLibrary.get(MY_SQL_USERNMAE)}"
    password: "${MyCustomSecretsLibrary.get(MY_SQL_PASSWORD)}"

MyCustomSecretsLibrary would be a standard Java/Spring library.

If you get a solution from overriding datasource bean will be "programmatically" , if you create any strategy to override properties  with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer will be "programmatically" and if you create an auto-configuration strategy in your dependencie library will be "programmatically".
